# Need help on adding openssl library

Tags: c, netbeans

I'm currently using Netbeans to write/compile C code.

I'm trying out a couple of openssl example codes that I found online, but I'm having a problem with the following error when I include the library:

```
Cannot find include file <openssl/conf.h>
Cannot find include file <openssl/evp.h>
Cannot find include file <openssl/err.h>
```

I was wondering how I can import openssl libraries.

Would someone teach me or point me to a direction where I can learn about importing libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the OpenSSL headers along with the static link libraries or dlls. Or download the OpenSSL library, compile the lib/dll for linkage then allow your compiler to locate the OpenSSL includes folder.

Library source is located here : https://github.com/openssl/openssl
Instructions on compiling here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation 
If you scroll down to the windows/OSX section. I imagine that's what you are using.